# Page error on first load after an app pool recycle

Tags: 2019

Any web part page throws an error the first time its loaded after the app pool recycles. Refreshing the page will then bring it up fine, and everything works until the next time the app pool is recycled. Pages that are not web part pages do not throw errors and load fine. For example, settings.aspx works fine, a newly created page with no web parts added will throw an error one time after an app pool recycle.

This also happens in central admin. Monitoring.aspx has web part zones, but no web parts, and throws an error. Pages like "manage servers in this farm", _admin/farmservers, works fine.

The log has the generic error of "Unexpected System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.", which I think is usually associated with custom solutions, but again, this occurs on pages with no customizations. Before this error in the log are many entries with "Config cache  Name lookup failure in derived cache for...". I've cleared the SP Config Cache, though that did not resolve the issue.

Any suggestions?

This is SharePoint 2019

Comment: Were you able to find the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Using warm up scripts will stop your users from seeing the error after the nightly app pool recycle.  https://github.com/spjeff/spbestwarmup
I know that is not exactly an answer, more of a work around.  I have been using SP2019 in several production environments and have not seen this issue.